# How does the minimal polynomial define a positive operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that T is a self-adjoint operator on the 2-dimensional complex inner product space. Suppose that the minimal polynomial of T is $$T^2-(a+c)T+(ac-|b|^2)I$$ a)Given that a, c are real numbers and b is complex. deduce from this that T is positive if and only if $$a+c>=0$$ and $$ac>= b^2$$ 
B) deduce from the polynomial that the eigenvalues a of T are real.

I have finished all the questions from my maths tutorial except these. We don't get answers and I am really stuck. Can somebody help me?

For part B I was thinking that eigenvalues are the roots to the minimal polynomial and using http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-%28a%2Bc%29x%2Bac-%7Cb%7C%5E2&x=0&y=0 we can see that the roots are real so there for the eigenvalues are real. Is this a correct approach?

For part A I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The characteristic polynomial of a $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ is:
$$
M^2- tr (M) +det(M)I
$$

Comment: In our current linear algebra course we haven't defined the trace of a matrix or the determinant. We are using Sheldon axlers book.

Comment: How you can you find the eigenvalues if you don't know what is a determinant?

Comment: We must solve for Tv=av where a is the eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with $Tv = \lambda v$. Plugging $v$ in the equation

$$ T^2 - (a + c)T + (ac - |b|^2)I = 0$$

you get

$$ (T^2 - (a+c)T + (ac - |b|^2)I)(v) = (\lambda^2 - (a+c)\lambda + (ac - |b|^2))v = 0. $$

Since $v \neq 0$, the eigenvalue must be a root of $\lambda^2 - (a+c)\lambda + (ac - |b|^2)$. Since $T$ is self adjoint, we must have two linearly independent eigenvectors. Since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is of degree two, $T$ must have two distinct eigenvalues. The operator $T$ will be positive if and only if the two eigenvalues will be non-negative. You can write them explicitly and see what condition you get.